# Minecraft chunks not loading

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to fly to an ocean, but I get to this border type thing, like it's not the world border, it's just a blank nothingness, like The End but in the Overworld. I have tried reloading chunks, leaving and rejoining, and resetting my render distance.
I'm not sure if it's because I made my world in 1.17 and it is now 1.18, and the chunks failed to load.
Could anyone help me fix this?

[image]

Comment: And also, I forgot to say, my game also seem bugged because when I drop something it just disappears and does not do a drop animation, my fireworks don't work, and if I'm flying here, I can't stop flying even if I take my elytra off.

Comment: Are you using any mod?

Comment: Are you on a server? If so, how is your ping?

Comment: i have used texture packs before but i removed them before this happened, and no this is a singleplayer world